# On-prem solution to design website with low code no code

Tags: web-development

I am looking for some low code no code website designing solution. For example, [wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) has some specific themes and is a big heavy weight application and may not suit for many enterprises. Sites like [wix.com](https://www.wix.com/) is good but is totally a third party. This is a good one - [Appian website designer](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/22.1/SAIL_Tutorial.html) but again it is a paid solution.

Can someone suggest something similar to [Appian website designer](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/22.1/SAIL_Tutorial.html) which I can install/configure on my local environment, and non UI developers (like python developers) can use it to design some websites?

Comment: What features do you need? If you just need simple static pages, [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) (famously used by GitHub Pages as the default static site generator) would be an option - pages are written in Markdown and everything else is just configuration files. On the other hand, if you need dynamic content like comments etc., you'll probably need something more sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I would look into Jekyll.. What I need is a page with fixed design, but should be able to call some APIs from UI, and render the output in form of some html elements to show what is returned from API

Comment: If you need to call an UI, then Jekyll won't be suitable and you need a proper server-side CMS or framework. No idea then, sorry.